# Chrome Extension - Want to loop through URLs (like a slideshow)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

noob js developer here.  This is my first post.

I want to loop through URLs in chrome, changing the URL every fifteen seconds.

My code is not doing it, it is jumping directly to the last URL and it is not pausing.

The SetTimeOut does not seem to be working properly.

I can't find anything online that helps.

Here is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url : "http://www.cbc.ca"} . 
    updateURL("http://www.tsn.ca.", 15000)
    updateURL("http://www.cnn.com", 15000)
})

function updateURL(url, ms) { 
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id,{url : url});
        setTimeOut(function () {chrome.tabs.reload();}, ms);
    });
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  or any other ideas on how to do this?  I think what I want to do is very simple, but I'm stuck.

thanks!